# How to group by with grouping set calculated fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Have query like this :

```
select coalesce(sp.name, 'SUM') COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT as name,
count(*) as [count],
(CASE WHEN sp.amounts like '%;' THEN SUBSTRING(sp.amounts,0,CHARINDEX(';',sp.amounts)) ELSE sp.amounts END) - cms.comm as [price],
cms.comm as comm,
ISNULL(MAX(fixed_amount),0.00) as ac, 
(cms.comm - ISNULL(MAX(fixed_amount),0.00)) as [mo],
(((CASE WHEN sp.amounts like '%;' THEN SUBSTRING(sp.amounts,0,CHARINDEX(';',sp.amounts)) ELSE sp.amounts END) - cms.comm) + (cms.comm - ISNULL(MAX(fixed_amount),0.00)))  as [hgf],
MAX(cms.[cc])*COUNT(*) as [zk],
(CASE WHEN sp.amounts like '%;' THEN SUBSTRING(sp.amounts,0,CHARINDEX(';',sp.amounts)) ELSE sp.amounts END) amount
,(count(*)) * ((((CASE WHEN sp.amounts like '%;' THEN SUBSTRING(sp.amounts,0,CHARINDEX(';',sp.amounts)) ELSE sp.amounts END) - cms.comm) + (cms.comm - ISNULL(MAX(fixed_amount),0.00)))) as [sg]
from auth
inner join sp on sp.id = auth.p_id  
left join c on auth.p_id = c.p_id and c.a_id = @a_id and CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) between [start_date] and end_date
outer apply (SELECT .....) cms          
WHERE ...
group by grouping sets( (sp.name,c_id,sp.amounts,cms.comm), (c_id))
```

The response of query is :

```
name    count   price   comm    a_comm  mo      hgf     sg
a1      633     14.4    0.6     0.6         0   14.4    9115.2
a2      1858    19.15   0.85    1.06    -0.21   18.94   35190.52
a3      362     19.1    0.9     1.06    -0.16   18.94   6856.28
SUM     2853    NULL    NULL    2.72    NULL    NULL    NULL
b1      4       97.5    2.5     0       2.5     100     400
b2      1242    14.625  0.375   0       0.375   15      18630
b3      1736    19.5    0.5     0       0.5     20      34720
SUM     2982    NULL    NULL    0       NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Query works perfect,the only one problem what I have it does not sum that fields which I calculate and brings null . For example:(hgf,mo and etc.). How to sum that fields ? Output must be like :

```
name    count   price   comm    a_comm  mo      hgf     sg
a1      633     14.4    0.6     0.6         0   14.4    9115.2
a2      1858    19.15   0.85    1.06    -0.21   18.94   35190.52
a3      362     19.1    0.9     1.06    -0.16   18.94   6856.28
SUM     2853    52.65   2.35    2.72    -0.37   52.28   51162.01
b1      4       97.5    2.5     0       2.5     100     400
b2      1242    14.625  0.375   0       0.375   15      18630
b3      1736    19.5    0.5     0       0.5     20      34720
SUM     2982    131.625 3.375   0       3.375   135     53750
```

Comment: Chances are you're missing a ISNULL() around a value/expression that can be NULL before you SUM on it.

Comment: For instance in the calculation for `mo` you are missing an ISNULL on `comm`.

Comment: thank you both comments helps me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the NULL results are due to NULLS in the fields used in the calculations that are not handled by an ISNULL.

You have a NULL for `comm`, therefore you get a NULL for `mo` which uses `comm` in its calculation.